# Insert a Map in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to insert map data into a DynamoDB table using API Gateway. Here's my payload:

```
{
"TableName":"OrderDB",
"Item":{
    "_id": {"S":"04FA887FP2S5R"},
    "_rev": {"S":"9-12e098e2490e1b7c9782597226689403"},
    "_merchantId":{"S":"AXN3EKXT0SJ61"},
    "doc":{"M":{"something":"storedHere"} }
}
```

And my body mapping template in API Gateway:

```
{ 
  "TableName": "$input.path('$.TableName')",
  "Item": $input.json('$.Item')
}
```

Everything works as expected if I remove the **doc** item from the payload. With trying to post with the map I get the following error:

```
{
  "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException",
  "Message": "Unexpected value type in payload"
}
```

All of the examples that I see suggest using the DynamoDB document mapping object, but I don't think this is possible for me because I'm using API Gateway to connect directly to DynamoDB. Is it possible to insert a map this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map entry needs the same format as the rest of the items, so instead of `"doc":{"M":{"something":"storedHere"} }` it should be `"doc":{"M":{"something":"S": "storedHere"} }`

Comment: That did the trick! So it seems as though if I'm using AWS Service option in API Gateway I can't just insert JSON objects, each object key has to have a data type. Not a good solution in my opinion, I was hoping to just throw the JSON in there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can still get there, but you'd have to do some object mapping. So no, you can't just throw raw JSON at API Gateway integrated with DynamoDB without transforming the data, but you can if you take the extra step of a transform.